# Bugsnag Error UnhandledRejection - Rejection reason was not an Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bugsnag

Our Rails app in production suddenly getting this rejection error

```
errorClass: UnhandledRejection
errorMessage: Rejection reason was not an Error. See "Promise" tab for more detail.
severity: error

unknown file · unknown method
```

**Not much of a log to debug what causes this issue.**

We're currently using `bugsnag.js.min version 6.1.0`

Is it fixed in latest version `6.5.0`?
Or any fix needed on our Rails app side?

Comment: Is it coming from IE users only?

Comment: Hi @draganstankovic it happens in different platform and browsers. Like Chrome in windows 7, MacOs, Chrome Mobile WebView => Android,  
Mobile Safari => iOS  and more...